# Error help needed

Tags: error, log

I have the following error being given to me but am not sure how to fix it

```
2014-11-13T13:29:12+00:00 ERR (3): Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Netzarbeiter_GroupsCatalog_Helper_Data::addGroupsFilterToProductCollection() must be an instance of Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Collection, instance of Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection given, called in /someUnixPath/app/code/community/Netzarbeiter/GroupsCatalog/Model/Catalog/Layer.php on line 37 and defined  in /someUnixPath/app/code/community/Netzarbeiter/GroupsCatalog/Helper/Data.php on line 475
```

Can anyone tell me what is causing this error or what I have to do to fix it?

Comment: This is about a 3rd party module, without knowing anything more it is impossible to troubleshoot this.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a third party module, please contact the support.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing the wrong parameter to `Netzarbeiter_GroupsCatalog_Helper_Data::addGroupsFilterToProductCollection()`.  Hope that helps.  True a different one.

Comment: If I remove teh 3rd party module it makes the site give a major error. 
Can you give me any pointers as to how to track the bug down? I am very new to Magento unfortunately.

Comment: The error code given displays the line and location of the function call.  Look there as to what paramter is being passed to the specific function.  Look how the function is defined and what parameter it is expecting.  Give it that parameter and the error should go away.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't make sense.

The error shouldn't happen, because the collection you are passing as argument is a child class of the one expected:

```
class Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Collection 
  extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection
```